# Settings > Display > Navigation Bar > Background Color Options Suddenly Limited

Tags: samsung, settings, 7.0-nougat, samsung-galaxy-s-8

Shortly after buying my Samsung Galaxy S8, my Settings > Display > Navigation Bar screen looked like this:

[image]

I retrieved that image from Android Central.  Now, it looks like this:

[image]

Notice the significantly limited color selections in the "Background Color" section.  Also, the first image has a color picker, but the second image does not.  I'm wondering if a recent update eliminated these options.  Could any Galaxy S8 owners tell me if their settings are more similar to the first or second image?  Also, does anyone have a suggestion how I could bring back the color options from the first image?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't own a Galaxy S8 device, but it seems the recent update has removed or limited the background colours option. From [this article](https://www.sammobile.com/2017/06/14/latest-update-limits-color-options-for-galaxy-s8s-navigation-bar-background/) it is certainly the case:

> Samsung is pushing out a new software update for the Galaxy S8 and
>   Galaxy S8+ right now, and it looks like the company has decided to
>   limit the customization options for the navigation bar. Well, at least
>   when it comes to the choice of color for the navigation bar’s
>   background, as there is no longer an option to choose a custom color
>   from an RGB scale. In fact, Samsung has switched up the available
>   background colors, and the worst of it is that you can no longer use a
>   fully black navigation bar background.

Again here is the changelog of the update:

[image]

You could try other workarounds using apps to extend the range of nav colours as suggested with [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.damianpiwowarski.navbarapps) app from play store. (NavBar App)